# how does Google do the half finished ghost text in the main search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

when you start to type something familiar in the search bar, it will finish it in ghost text. since the text is non highlight-able i'm guessing it's a generated and positioned background image. Does anyone know how they actually do it? i want to build something like it.

Comment: its not image, its text only... and its a suggestion/auto complete kinda thing

Comment: I am aware of what it is. how are you certain it's text and not an image?

Comment: I am certain that it IS text because I have looked at the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's how google did it:

behind the transparent input box is a div containing the typed letters as well as a container with the "ghost" word. all of them are meticulously aligned so that the typed letters perfectly hide the letters of the "ghost word".

[image]

Comment: awesome! that's how i was thinking to do it if i couldn't figure out a better way.. but iguess it's legit enough seeming now.

Answer (score 2):

It's text. There are several divs in the same position. The text you enter and the grey autosuggest text are in two separate divs.

There's a text input there too, but it has no value while you're entering text. I assume it's populated with javascript at some point if needed.

Anyway, you can confirm this by typing a few letters in the search box, right clicking, hitting "inspect element," and poking around a bit in the DOM inspector.

My interpretation of what's going on is this:

1. You type in a textbox
2. The textbox is immediately cleared and whatever you typed there is placed in the "black" div
3. The autosuggest routine takes place, and the "grey" div is filled with the rest of the word being suggested.

Comment: There is no reason to clear the input-text-box. It's enough to make it not visible. By not clearing the input-text-box, you let the browser handle all editing (cursor movements, cut/copy/paste etc). You just need to read the current value of the input-text-box when it has changed and do your autosuggest then.

Comment: Well, it seems that the way google's doing it, the only text input at that location is always empty, even if you've entered some text. I'm not sure why it's like that.

Comment: No, it's not empty when you have written something. Proof: `alert(document.getElementById("lst-ib").value);`

Comment: Also, look at what color the input element has: `<input id="lst-ib" class="gsfi" type="text" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" size="41" title="Sök" value="" dir="ltr" style="left: 0pt; border: medium none; padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 2px; margin: 0pt; width: 100%; outline: medium none; top: 1px; overflow: hidden; background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 5; color: transparent;" spellcheck="false">`. Isn't it `color: transparent;`?

Comment: @some apparently google is serving us two different things. Either that or I really need sleep.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it could be dependent on the browser and the language.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually text, not image. The same question got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285139/show-ghosted-example-text-in-a-field-and-then-clear-it-onblur).

Also, here is another little snippet (Javascript) that works:

```
<FORM action="http://www.domain.com" method="post">
<INPUT type="text" size="25" value="Enter Your Default Text Here" onFocus="if(this.value       == 'Enter Your Default Text Here') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '')     {this.value = 'Enter Your Default Text Here';}" />
<INPUT type=submit value=Submit>
</FORM>
```

Comment: that's not what i'm talking about. this is more complex than a simple default text toggle. it finishes words in ghost text. just type "fac" in the search bar and you'll see it finish it with "ebook" in ghost text.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Well for that to work you'd have to first build up possible strings and then use @some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not an image, but text in a div-tag.

You can use firebug och similar to get the exact code, below you see the important elements of how they do it. Of course you need some javascript too:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 25px;">
<input type="text">
<div>goo</div>
<div>google</div>
</div>
```

( I entered `goo` as you see in the first div-tag after the input-tag, and they put `google` as a suggestion in the second one. If you look at the real code you see that they have different style-attributes to get the different colors. I removed much of it because it wasn't important in the answer exactly what colors they where using)